Difference of suprema is less than or equal to supremum of difference
I can’t prove the following inequality:
$$|\sup f-\sup g|\le\sup|f-g|$$
in $[a,b]$, given $f,g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$.

Have you thought about it yet? Edit your question to include your attempt.

$$
\sup|f - g| = \sup\{|\sup f - \inf g| \cup|\inf f - \sup g|:f, g : [a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\} \geq |\sup f- \sup g|
$$
Because the point $\sup |f - g|$ is contained in the epigraph of $|\sup f - \sup g|$.

Let $M$ denote $\sup|f-g|$. Also, abbreviate $\overline f:=\sup f$ and $\overline g:=\sup g$.
For each $x\in[a,b]$,
$$
f(x)=f(x)-g(x)+g(x)\le M+g(x)\le M+\overline g.
$$
Optimizing the choice of $x$:
$$
\overline f\le M+\overline g.
$$
Reversing roles:
$$
\overline g\le M+\overline f.
$$
Taken together these yield
$$
-M\le \overline f-\overline g\le M.
$$

Why the down vote?
